# Trouble with Multiple Sankey Subplots in Plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

So I’m stuck trying to create a plot with multiple Sankey diagrams. Specifically, I keep getting an error that says **"Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Sankey: 'xaxis'"**. This seems to be invoked when the script gets to the **append_trace** command. Here is a simple example code, which I run in a Jupyter notebook:

```
import plotly.tools as tools
import plotly.offline as offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go

offline.init_notebook_mode(connected = True)

trace1 = go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
        pad = 15,
        thickness = 20,
        line = dict(
            color = "black",
            width = 0.5
        ),
        label = ["Joe", "Molly", "Gavin", "Octavio", "Leslie", "Natasha"],
        color = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "brown", "magenta"]
    ),
    link = dict(
        source = [0,1,3],
        target = [5,5,0],
        value = [6,8,3]
    )
)

trace2 = go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
        pad = 15,
        thickness = 20,
        line = dict(
            color = "black",
            width = 0.5
        ),
        label = ["Russia", "Gambia", "Sweden", "Bolivia", "Timor-Leste", "Kazakhstan", "Bhutan"],
        color = ["red", "black", "brown", "magenta", "yellow", "blue", "orange"]
    ),
    link = dict(
        source = [0,1,4,6],
        target = [7,7,7,3],
        value = [6,8,3,3]
    )
)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 1)

fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)

fig['layout'].update(
    title = "Basic Sankey Diagram with Two Subplots",
    font = dict(
      size = 10
    )
)

offline.iplot(fig)
```

When I run it, I get the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-dd6268edf7ab> in <module>
     37 fig = tools.make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 1)
     38 
---> 39 fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
     40 fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)
     41 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in append_trace(self, trace, row, col)
   1222 """, DeprecationWarning)
   1223 
-> 1224         self.add_trace(trace=trace, row=row, col=col)
   1225 
   1226     def _set_trace_grid_position(self, trace, row, col):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in add_trace(self, trace, row, col)
   1069         return self.add_traces(data=[trace],
   1070                                rows=[row] if row is not None else None,
-> 1071                                cols=[col] if col is not None else None
   1072                                )[0]
   1073 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in add_traces(self, data, rows, cols)
   1152         if rows is not None:
   1153             for trace, row, col in zip(data, rows, cols):
-> 1154                 self._set_trace_grid_position(trace, row, col)
   1155 
   1156         # Make deep copy of trace data (Optimize later if needed)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in _set_trace_grid_position(self, trace, row, col)
   1259                                 "An axis object for ({r},{c}) subplot "
   1260                                 "cell got deleted.".format(r=row, c=col))
-> 1261             trace['xaxis'] = ref[0]
   1262             trace['yaxis'] = ref[1]
   1263 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in __setitem__(self, prop, value)
   2823             # ### Validate prop ###
   2824             if prop not in self._validators:
-> 2825                 self._raise_on_invalid_property_error(prop)
   2826 
   2827             # ### Get validator for this property ###

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in _raise_on_invalid_property_error(self, *args)
   3006                                  full_obj_name=full_obj_name,
   3007                                  invalid_str=invalid_str,
-> 3008                                  prop_descriptions=self._prop_descriptions))
   3009 
   3010     def update(self, dict1=None, **kwargs):

ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Sankey: 'xaxis'
```

I am NOT specifying **xaxis** in my traces, so where the hell is this coming from? Seems like this part may have something to do with it:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in _set_trace_grid_position(self, trace, row, col)
   1259                                 "An axis object for ({r},{c}) subplot "
   1260                                 "cell got deleted.".format(r=row, c=col))
-> 1261             trace['xaxis'] = ref[0]
   1262             trace['yaxis'] = ref[1]
   1263
```

Is this a bug? I have no idea.

Somebody help!

Comment: Any way to get titles for each of the subplots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cross-posted this question on Plotly community forums [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/invalid-property-specified-for-object-of-type-plotly-graph-objs-sankey-xaxis/21603?u=rkarimov) and received an answer that solved it (mostly). I'll copy the answer here so it's preserved even if the link goes dead.

> The trouble you’re running into is that *make_subplots* and *append_trace* only work for cartesian trace types right now. This is something we’re planning to improve for version 4, but in the meantime, the best approach is to specify the position of each sankey trace individually using the domain property.

```
import plotly.offline as offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go

offline.init_notebook_mode(connected = True)

trace1 = go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
        pad = 15,
        thickness = 20,
        line = dict(
            color = "black",
            width = 0.5
        ),
        label = ["Joe", "Molly", "Gavin", "Octavio", "Leslie", "Natasha"],
        color = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "brown", "magenta"]
    ),
    link = dict(
        source = [0,1,3],
        target = [5,5,0],
        value = [6,8,3]
    ),
    domain={
        'x': [0, 0.45]
    }
)

trace2 = go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
        pad = 15,
        thickness = 20,
        line = dict(
            color = "black",
            width = 0.5
        ),
        label = ["Russia", "Gambia", "Sweden", "Bolivia", "Timor-Leste", "Canada", "Bhutan"],
        color = ["red", "black", "brown", "magenta", "yellow", "blue", "orange"]
    ),
    link = dict(
        source = [0,1,4,6],
        target = [7,7,7,3],
        value = [6,8,3,3]
    ),
    domain={
        'x': [0.55, 1.0]
    }
)

data = [trace1, trace2]

layout =  go.Layout(
    title = "Basic Sankey Diagram",
    font = dict(
      size = 10
    )
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

This produces two subplots side by side:

[Sankey subplots horizontal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7gtW.png)

Instead of specifying 'x' in domain, we can specify 'y' to position the subplots vertically.

It's a nice hack, absent the built-in support for Sankey subplots. The only drawback is that I cannot see how one would specify individual titles for the subplots.

Comment: As of plotly 5.11, this is still the working solution, as Sankey plots aren't supported in plotly subplots (https://plotly.com/python/subplots/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this way](https://plot.ly/pandas/sankey-diagram/) without append operation:

Add this to the definition of both traces.

```
type='sankey',
```

Define your two subplots as data array.

```
data = Data([trace1, trace2])
```

Define `fig`:

```
fig = dict(data=[data], layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, validate=False)
```

Finally you need to add the definition of your layout using a dictionary as shown in my referenced post.

Comment: This will result in two subplots superimposed.

Comment: Leave out the round brackets, then it should work out.

Comment: Didn't work for me as well, without the round brackets (plotly 5.11, the Data class is deprecated anyway). Also, I think since the traces are already Sankey objects, there's no need to define a `type='sankey'`; and finally, the referenced post does not show how to define a layout for multiplot (maybe I missed it)?